# Bash, Gnuplot: plot multiple chosen column pairs from one datafile into one plot

Tags: bash, shell, variables, gnuplot, using

I'm making a script to plot desired pairs of columns of a datafile in a window. But i cant figure out how to make gnuplot accept arguments to the `using` command.

my code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
filee=$1
shift 1
cols=$@

gnuplot -p << eof
#TESTS--------------------------------
print "gnuplot--starts----------------"

print "cols-var is:     $cols"
print "filee-name is:   $filee"

print "pair-vars are:"
do for [pair in "$cols"] {print pair}

print "-------------------------------"
#END TESTS----------------------------"


set term wxt 1 size 1500,900 title 'columns of $filee'
set key top left
set grid
set xrange [2:8]
set yrange [-0.02:0.02]
set format y "%g"
plot for [pair in "$cols"] '$filee' u pair  
eof
```

If instead of `pair` as the argument to `u` i use `1:3` or `1:2` or whatever i get the correct number of plots, but of course they are all identical. I tried a lot of things and everything seem to be working besides that `u` doesn't accept a variable. The output wher running this is:

```
$ ./cploter written.dat 1:2 1:3 1:4
gnuplot--starts----------------
cols-var is:    1:2 1:3 1:4
filee-name is:  written.dat
pair-vars are:
1:2
1:3
1:4
-------------------------------
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

Some help with this issue would be appreciated:)

EDIT: as `u` doesn't seem to be accepting the loop through its arguments I settled for the code below. If You know a different approach to plot desired column pairs into one plot, please leave a comment or answer:)

```
#!/bin/bash
fil=$1; xx=$2; y1=$3; y2=$4
gnuplot -p <<- eof
set term wxt 1 size 1500,900 title 'columns of $filee'
set key top left
set format y "%g"
plot for [i=${y1}:${y2}] '$fil' u ${xx}:i w l t 'Column ${xx}:'.i
eof
```

I'm on gnuplot 4.6. using `for [i in $range]` does not work in this case for some reason. Using variables `ys(i)=word("$yes",i), xs=word("$xes",i)` and `plot for [i=1:3] '$fil' u xs(i):ys(i) w l` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer; there are a few other ways of working around this situation)

I get a different error running your script (gnuplot 5.0)

```
line 0: warning: no column with header "1:2"
```

but I think the source of the problem is the same. The issue is that gnuplot is looking for a single column with the name "1:2" rather than interpreting the token "1:2" as a two-column `using` specification.

If you only want to plot pairs of the form `1:2`, you can just pass the second column indices as arguments to your script and use the plot command

```
plot for [pair in "$cols"] '$filee' u 1:column(int(pair))
```

Comment: I think you must use `using 1:(column(pair))`.

Comment: @Christoph, I tried that as well and it did not work properly. It acts as if I had issued `columnhead(pair)` and gives an error `line 0: warning: no column with header "3"`, for example.

Comment: You are right, `column(p)` checks the data type of variable `p`: if it is a string, it is used as column label to select a column. Otherwise it is used a column index. A value of `"3"` isn't casted to int. You must do this yourself with `using 1:(column(int(pair)))`.

Comment: I kind of settled for this kind of structure, see the updated post. Thanks anyway. If you come up with something, please post it. Sadly the `[pair in "$cols"] is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[pair in "$cols"]` works fine, provided all the rest is also correct. The following example works fine:

File `test.dat`

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

and the script `plot.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
filee=$1
shift 1
cols=$@

gnuplot -p <<EOF
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
plot for [col in "$cols"] '$filee' u 1:(column(int(col)))

EOF
```

Call this script with

```
./plot.sh test.dat 2 3 4
```